# Google Sheets: DCOUNTA for date that falls in specific week number

Tags: google-sheets

I'm still quite the beginner when it comes to more complex formula in Google Sheets. I'm trying to do an analysis for my company, the data is in a db-like table (CSV import), one of the columns contains a date, another one a status. I want to count how many times a certain status falls into a given week.

Here's an example (sheet "data"):

| Status | Date |
| --- | --- |
| resolved | 11/13/2022 |
| resolved | 11/13/2022 |
| resolved | 11/12/2022 |
| created | 11/10/2022 |
| resolved | 11/05/2022 |
| created | 11/04/2022 |
| created | 11/02/2022 |

First three rows are week 44, the others week 43. I want a table that looks like this:

| week | created | resolved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | 2 | 1 |
| 44 | 1 | 3 |

So example for cell B2 of the result table have `=DCOUNTA(data!A1:B8,"Status",{"Status","Date";"created",[WEEK == A2]})`
(what I need in square brackets)

The problem I have is that the WEEK function expects an input, so how can I circumvent that? Does the DCOUNTA function work for this or do I need another function?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({ISOWEEKNUM(B2:B), A2:A}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2 
  label Col1'week'"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, QUERY({ISOWEEKNUM(raw!C2:C), raw!B2:B}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2 
  label Col1'week'"), SEQUENCE(1, COUNTUNIQUE(raw!B2:B))+1, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that's something completely new for me.
Thanks a lot for your answer!
I'll need to carefully take a look and see if I can extrapolate it to other functions I need.

Comment: The problem I see is that I need the result numbers to go in arbitrary places...
Is there any possibility that the cells of the result table contain formulas that reference the outside values?

Comment: @Alpha23 can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: I'll create a mock-up tomorrow, the original contains sensitive data. Thanks for your involvement!

Comment: Sorry it took me longer, had to clear something up first.
Here's a mockup: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mu0UN-kVZ3imdDbxjH_bbv6SIxpFDzifdrjoO7pkues/edit?usp=sharing
The table on the first sheet needs to be filled but I also need to be able to change the weeks or users, so I need a formula in each cell. The original raw data has 13 columns and over 17,000 lines.

Comment: Thanks for editing the sheet! I'll see what I can extract from it.
Am I right in thinking that there is no formula that can potentially be entered in every table cell of the first sheet (B2:D53) without some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's how I've solved my issue.

I added an additional column to my raw data with

`=CONCATENATE(ISOWEEKNUM(L2),"-",IF(AND(MONTH(L2)=1,ISOWEEKNUM(L2)>1),YEAR(L2)-1,YEAR(L2)))`

so I have the week number and the year in a single cell (it's a historical analysis). The if-clauses are for cases where the first days of the year are part of the last week of the previous year.

I could then easily access what I need by creating a table that has all the [week-year] combinations as header and the users in the first column of the lines.
Each cell looks something like this:

`=DCOUNTA(RAW!$A:$O,"start",{"user","start";$B9,C$1})`

where B9 holds the user name and C1 said string combination.